# What is a "house of Madanu" and a "gate of Madanu"?

Tags: mesopotamia, rituals, hittite, akkadian

The Hittite ritual CTH 432 ("The Ritual for Depression") mentions laying out certain patterns in flour, starting at §3.24:

> *namma-kan* É <sup>d</sup>*MADANI* *Ù* É <sup>d</sup>*ṢAR*[…
> *gulašzi nu-kan* KÁ <sup>d</sup>*MADANI IŠ*[…
>
> Next, he shall mark out the Temple of Madanu and the Temple of Ṣar[panitu…]
> and then the Gate of Madanu wi[th…]

The context implies that flour is supposed to be used for this (a few lines earlier *IŠTU* ZÌDA "by using flour").

But what does it mean to "mark out the Temple of Madanu with flour"? Similarly for "the Gate of Madanu"? Is this known from other Hittite or Akkadian rituals? (Since this particular ritual is a mix of Hittite and Akkadian magic.)

(The word for "temple" here, "É", literally means "house", so this could also be read as "the House of Madanu".)